# Passing dynamic boolean props to a VueJS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

How can I attach dynamic properties to a VueJS Component using VuetifyJS?

I have the following VuetifyJS code example that creates a select field element:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire" style="padding: 10px; ">
    <v-select 
      v-model="selectField"
      :items="items" 
      multiple attach chips>  
    </v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      selectField: '', 
      items: [
        'item1', 
        'item2', 
        'item3'
      ],
      booleanProperties: [
        'multiple', 
        'attach', 
        'chips'
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

This creates a functional VuetifyJS select component, however I want to know how to pass the boolean props `multiple, attach, chips` to the select element as data properties so they do not have to be specified explicitly in the component declaration.

For example: I want to add the props: `multiple, attach, chips` defined within the data array element `booleanProperties` while still being able to define the component without having them specified. This way it works dynamically for any prop I pass.

Something similar to the following pseudocode example.

```
<v-select 
    v-model="selectField"
    :items="items"
    v-for="(booleanProperties) as boolProp">         
</v-select>
```

How can I pass/specify the data props: `multiple, attach, chips` dynamically for the `v-select` element?

Here is a code example of what I am referring to.
https://codepen.io/deftonez4me/pen/NWRLWKE

Comment: Are you asking about `:chips="hasChips"` for example, or about how to avoid explicitly typing a "chips" attribute/binding?

Comment: How to avoid explicitly specifying the chips attribute at all so it works dynamically for any boolean property I pass. See revised question content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `v-bind` without specifying the key/property, and then passing an object into it, i.e. `v-bind="additionalProps"`. As per [VueJS v2 documentation on `v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind):

> When used without an argument, can be used to bind an object containing attribute name-value pairs.

You can also merge your `items` binding into the object returned by `additionalProps` then, for brevity. Example based on your code.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      selectField: '', 
      additionalProps: {
        items: [
          'item1', 
          'item2', 
          'item3'
        ],
        multiple: true,
        attach: true,
        chips: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.3.16/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.3.16/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire" style="padding: 10px; ">
    <v-select 
      v-model="selectField"
      v-bind="additionalProps">  
    </v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can go simply as this:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire" style="padding: 10px; ">
    <v-select 
      v-model="selectField"
      :items="items" 
      :multiple="multiple"
      :attach="attach"
      :chips="chips">  
    </v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Then you can declare the props as before:

```
  props: [
    'multiple', 
    'attach', 
    'chips'
  ]
```

Or a bit more specific like this:

```
props: {
        multiple: {
          type: Boolean
        },
        attach: {
          type: Boolean
        },
        chips: {
          type: Boolean
        }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a method that would work for any dynamic property I passed without having to specify anything within the component declaration.